# DIrectX 11 2D Game Engine using Direct 3D (C++)

Tags: c++, 2d, game-engine, directx-11, direct3d11

I have scoured the internet looking for assistance in creating a 2D game engine in DirectX 11 using Direct 3D (instead of the Direct 2D wrapper, which most sites seem to agree isn't ideal).

I have found a plethora of resources detailing how to create a 3D game engine, but as this is my first engine attempt, I'd rather go with 2D and save myself the trouble of 3D math... I have also found a decent amount of information and textbooks on creating a 2D engine in DirectX 9, but it's my understanding that DirectX 9 handles a lot of these things very differently than DirectX 11 --and I'd rather be learning the latest and greatest (ignoring DIrectX 12 obviously, which many sites seem to agree isn't ideal for 2D)

**Therefore, can anyone recommend any good sites, textbooks, videos, tutorials etc.. that could help me build a 2D game engine in C++ with DirectX 11 3D? --or, should I be doing something completely different?**

Some other notes:
I don't want to use OpenGL; 
I have already looked at: http://www.directxtutorial.com/LessonList.aspx?listid=11 and http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut11.html to name a few.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're new to game programming in general, so making a **game engine** might be a bit of a stretch. I'd get more familiar with game programming first, so you'll know what features game programmers might want. I'd start by creating a simple game with an existing 2D library (or a library that allows 2D), like [SDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer).

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem**

Comment: Look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and it's [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). You can do a lot with ``SpriteBatch`` just like you could with XNA Game Studio.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn That's a great suggestion, thank you! I had been looking into XNA.

Comment: @Frecklefoot I've created some games in Unity before, but I find that the use of an editor like that has really been black-boxing my learning, which is why I want to create my own engine.

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p91FvlnyOyo&list=PLKK11Ligqitij8r6hd6tfqqesh3T_xWJA&index=1) 9-part tutorial playlist on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

DirectX 2D is what you want if you will only do 2D.  It is hardware accelerated and you can use the math library that is shared with DirectX 11 & 12 to ease you into the workings of a 3D Engine.  If you will eventually convert it to 3D, Chuck W. Comment on DirextX tool kit is a good one.
Chuck, BTW, are you still writing a DirectX 12 Sprite batch class you mention last year?  Would be awesome to see that.

Comment: I'm hesitant to use DirectX 2D because I've heard a number of negative remarks about it... http://braid-game.com/news/2009/01/a-demonstration-that-direct2d-is-patently-ridiculous/

Comment: Consider what you want to do.  Your post say "assistance in creating a 2D game engine" which is graphics + game code.  Do you want 80% time on the game code and 20% on coding graphcis? or vise versus?  This being your first engine I would not try to learn HLSL and the CPU/GPU handshaking that has to happen, leave that up to an API like DirectX2D.  You have enough to worry about with bounding boxes, collisions, state machines, user input, action response control, sound, asset loading, animation, path finding, etc. - Good luck and use stackover flow for all those queries, it has helped me a lot.

Comment: [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/) is now available including ``SpriteBatch``. See [this tutorial lesson](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Sprites-and-textures).

Comment: Awesome, thanks Chuck for making this a reality.  That is one of the best classes I have used in DirectX 11, glad to see it in 12!